# Is there an Eclipse Plugin To Add a Dependency to a jar from SVN?

Tags: java, eclipse, dependencies

Is there an easy way to include a JAR as a dependency of a project from SVN in Eclipse. Like an Eclipse plugin or something like that?

I don't want to use Maven, it would be overkill for this project.

**Update :**

We have 2 projects :

- Project A -> gives projecta.jar
- Project B -> needs projecta.jar

projecta.jar is commited in SVN automatically

In Eclipse, ProjectB needs a dependency on projecta.jar to build.

I would like to add a dependency to the build path on projecta.jar, in Eclipse, directly to our SVN repository. For the moment, we can only do that on the file system.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve. Can you be more detailed?

Comment: If the svn repo is local then just add as an external jar file and point to the jar file.  Or are you asking if there's a way to get a jar file from a remote svn repo and add it to the build path?

Comment: Have you tried svn:externals?

Comment: @Elias If I understand correctly, it's some kind of "include" but directly in the SVN repository? That might work even better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at how to [include a common sub-project](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-howto-common-projects.html#tsvn-howto-common-externals)

There's another sections in the same webpage that might be helpful...